# Does Oracle Cloud Kubernetes CSI implementation depend on the flexvolumes?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Does the Oracle Cloud Kubernetes CSI implementation depend on the flex-volumes?

In other words, in order to use the OCI CSI (i.e. `csi-oci-node` driver and `csi-oci-controller` driver), do I need to deploy `oci-block-volume-provisioner` and `oci-flexvolume-driver`?

Ref: https://github.com/oracle/oci-cloud-controller-manager#setup-and-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not required to deploy `oci-block-volume-provisioner` and `oci-flexvolume-driver` to use OCI CSI driver.

Please refer https://github.com/oracle/oci-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/container-storage-interface.md for steps on setting up OCI CSI driver.

You can also check the fully-managed, scalable, and highly available Container Engine for Kubernetes(OKE) service from OCI which comes pre-installed with the OCI CSI driver & the associated StorageClass at https://www.oracle.com/cloud-native/container-engine-kubernetes/ & https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Concepts/contengoverview.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying of OCI-block-volume-provisioned and oci-flexvolume-drive in order to use OCI CSI is not mandatory but recommended.

OCI Flexvolume Driver: It enables mounting of OCI block storage volumes to Kubernetes Pods via the Flexvolume plugin interface.

OCI Volume Provisioner: The OCI Volume Provisioner enables dynamic provisioning of storage resources when running Kubernetes on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. It uses the OCI Flexvolume Driver to bind storage resources to Kubernetes nodes. The volume provisioner offers support for Block Volume.

Comment: Thanks. What do I loose if I choose not to deploy the FlexVolume Driver and the Volume Provisioner on a self-managed cluster in OCI? Apparently with CSI exclusively I can also create and attach blockvolumes.